# How to print the row and columns of the value you're looking for in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I made this dataframe

```
alp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
s = "carl"

for i in s: 
    alp = alp.replace(i,"")
    
jaa = s+alp
x = list(jaa)


array = np.array(x)
re = np.reshape(array,(6,6))

dt = pd.DataFrame(re)
dt.columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dt.index = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dt

    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   c   a   r   l   b   d
2   e   f   g   h   i   j
3   k   m   n   o   p   q
4   s   t   u   v   w   x
5   y   z   0   1   2   3
6   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

I want to search a value , and print its row(index) and column.
For example, 'h', the output i want is 2,4.
Is there any way to get that output?

Comment: try `dt.stack().eq("h").idxmax()`

Answer (score 1):

```
row, col = np.where(dt == "h")
print(dt.index[row[0]], dt.columns[col[0]])
```